# windows command prompt - execute command in new process

Tags: cmd.exe, process

in command prompt I execute this line

```
java -jar <path_to_jd_gui_jar> <path_to_jar_file>
```

which opens a the jd-gui (jar viewer) to view a jar file. But if I close the cmd window it automatically closes the jd-gui window too. How can I execute this command so that the window that opens is independed from the command prompt?

I m guessing it has to start in a new process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [javaws Command Line](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/javaws.html) :

```
javaws -jar <path_to_jd_gui_jar> <path_to_jar_file>
```

If you wish to disassociate it from the console where you entered
the command, use the Windows [START command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html):

```
start "" javaws -jar <path_to_jd_gui_jar> <path_to_jar_file>
```

You may also use this in a batch file.

Comment: this starts a new terminal window (java terminal this time) and if I close it the jd-gui closes again.

Comment: You may need in this case the `javaws` command.